# Youtube oauth2 without web service - urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, youtube

So i created youtube api project on google cloud. I tested getting auth code via urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob redirect-uri, i don t want to make webservice to auth my account. Everything is good because i am getting code in the browser but i have the problem with POSTing to the api this auth code. When i am trying to post authentication code via RestMan (sth like postman) it shows me that:

```
    <html lang=en>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
<title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
<style nonce="CIsxxpEHaaEHNiQiddzf7Q">
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{color:#222;text-align:unset;margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px;}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}pre{white-space:pre-wrap;}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
</style>
<main id="af-error-container" role="main"><a href=//www.google.com><span id=logo aria-label=Google role=img></span></a>
    <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
        <p>The requested URL was not found on this server. <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
</main>
```

My data in RestMan:

URL: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token/`

Raw body: `code=MYCODE&client_id=MYCLIENTID&client_secret=MYSECRET&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code`

I think it can be problem with body in redirect_uri part. Can someone advice me what should i write there? Need i create webservice authorization with localhost?

**EDIT:**
Okay i just used youtube client library for java.
Example codes are really helpful and connection should be safe.
Link: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/

Answer (score 0):

a) You're likely using the wrong URL. Use the Google discovery doc: https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration to find the token endpoint:

...

"token_endpoint": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",

...

b) Consider setting up localhost to get the authorization code and refresh token. See https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i just used youtube client library for java. Example codes are really helpful and connection should be safe. Link: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/